# How to create a transaction that only shows one transaction approve pop-up to the user?

Tags: web3.js, transactions, rpc, solana-wallet-adapter, anchor-lang

I want to add two instructions to a single transaction and only show one popup to user then he/she can approve ONLY ONE transaction. Tried with '@solana/web3.js' Transaction but it didn't worked as expected. Below shows the code that I implemented. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Can you edit this question to include the code in a code block instead of a screenshot please?

Comment: Can you describe all of the details about what didn't work as you expected, along with all relevant error messages and unexpected behaviours?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using some deprecated anchor methods. Try using the "method builder" approach, where the last statement is `.instruction()`.

There are some examples of this syntax on the Anchor repository: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/examples/tutorial/basic-1/tests/basic-1.js.